# Get JSON from response object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
<html>
<body>

    <form action="login.do" method="post">
        //.....

        <input type="submit" value ="send">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In my servlet I will be handle the request and send the json response back.
How can I get the json object from the response ?

But we can do this by calling a function when we click the button.

```
function(){
    $ajax(
        url:"login.do"
        success: function(data){
        //..... 
        }
    )
}
```

is there any way to do this? Or only using the function call we can do it?

Comment: your json string is probably in the data parameter of the success function. use dataType : "json" in your $.ajax() call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first argument of success callback that you call `data` is the json object so long as you include `dataType:'json'` in ajax options or use shorthand `$.post(url[,data][,function(json){}),'json'])` method

Read about success callback in $.ajax API :

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

EDIT: Using deffered method

```
var ajaxCall= $.post( url, dataToServer,'json')


 $.when( ajaxCall).then(function(data){
     var json =data;
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set the `dataType` to `json`, or you could use the short cut method [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

```
$.getJSON(your_url, function(data) {
  // data here is already an object.
  console.log(data);
});
```

***EDIT:*** `getJSON` will use `GET` request type, for `POST`, you could do

```
$.post(your_url, function(data) {
  // data here is already an object.
  console.log(data);
}, 'json');
```